# TYPO3 - Attempt to insert record on page where this table is not allowed

Tags: php, typo3

I made a new extension with "sitepackage builder" to override the extension "bootstrap_package".

If I just change/overwrite codes in some files of `bootstrap_package` in `sitepackage`, the content-element is displayed and my changing is also displayed.
But if I add a new content-element in `sitepackage` builder, I have some problems.

I added a wizard "Carousel Small XXX" and some fields on a page "Carousel" like this:

[image]

If I create an item and change type like "Text and Image", then an error comes up:

[image]

`1: Attempt to insert record on page 'Carousel' (101) where this table, tx_carousel_item_xx, is not allowed`

Furthermore, my content element "Carousel Small XXX" isn't displayed in the frontend.
A table "tx_carousel_item_xx" is in a database, but there are no data in a database (the data didn't saved).

I tried these:

1. in ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('tx_carousel_item_xx');
$TCA['tx_carousel_item_xx']['ctrl']['security']['ignoreRootLevelRestriction'] = 1; 
$TCA['tx_carousel_item_xx']['ctrl']['rootLevel'] = -1; 
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('sys_file_reference');
$TCA['sys_file']['ctrl']['security']['ignoreRootLevelRestriction'] = 1; 
$TCA['sys_file']['ctrl']['rootLevel'] = -1; 
$TCA['sys_file_reference']['ctrl']['security']['ignoreRootLevelRestriction'] = 1; 
$TCA['sys_file_reference']['ctrl']['rootLevel'] = -1;
```

2. in TCA

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['carousel_small_xx'] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['carousel_small_xx'],
    [
        'showitem' => '
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.general;general,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.headers;headers,
                tx_carousel_item_xx,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:carousel.options,
                pi_flexform;LLL:EXT:bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Language/Backend.xlf:advanced,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.appearance,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.frames;frames,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.appearanceLinks;appearanceLinks,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:language,
                --palette--;;language,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
                --palette--;;hidden,
                --palette--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:palette.access;access,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:categories,
                categories,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:notes,
                rowDescription,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:extended,
        '
    ]
);

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'] = array_replace_recursive(
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns'],
    [
        'tx_carousel_item_strobelmuehle' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myextension/locallang_db.xml:company.employees',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'inline',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_carousel_item_strobelmuehle',
                'foreign_field' => 'pid',
                'foreign_table_field' => 'tt_content',
                'appearance' => [
                    'collapseAll' => 1,
                    'expandSingle' => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

3. in tsconfig

```
mod.web_list.allowedNewTables = tt_content, pages, tx_carousel_item_xx
```

4. Add a new table in a database

```
CREATE TABLE tx_carousel_item_xx (
    uid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    tt_content int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    KEY parent (pid),
    KEY t3ver_oid (t3ver_oid,t3ver_wsid),
    KEY language (l10n_parent,sys_language_uid)
);
```

5. in Typoscript

```
tt_content.carousel_small_xx >
tt_content.carousel_small_xx =< lib.contentElement
tt_content.carousel_small_xx {
    templateName = CarouselSmallxx
    dataProcessing {
        10 = BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
        20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        20 {
            table = tx_carousel_item_xx
            pidInList.field = pid
            where {
                data = field:uid
                intval = 1
                wrap = tt_content=|
            }
            orderBy = sorting
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = background_image
                    as = backgroundImage
                }
                20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                20 {
                    references.fieldName = image
                    as = images
                }
                1532633187 = BK2K\BootstrapPackage\DataProcessing\FlexFormProcessor
                1532633187 {
                    fieldName = background_image_options
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I read some artikels about this problem and changed the roorlevel in ext_tables.php.
But the error message comes up everytime. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Please check my codes for database too.
I can't save data in the table "tx_carousel_item_xx", if I added a record in my new content element. The database of the table seems like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yesnG.png)

Furthermore, I'm not sure, my codes in TCA. Especially 'foreign_table', 'foreign_field' and 'foreign_table_field'.

I added a new table in my database which "tx_carousel_item_xx" says. And I added a column "tx_carousel_item_xx" in "tt_content". Do I need one more table, if I use `'type' => 'inline'` in TCA and which tables should I write in 'foreign_table', 'foreign_field' and 'foreign_table_field'?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace **$TCA** with **$GLOBALS['TCA']** in your ext_tables.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed my codes to `$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_carousel_item_strobelmuehl']['ctrl']['rootLevel'] = -1; ` (of course other codes also with  $GLOBALS['TCA']), but the error still comes up...